# Kernel error in gem5 when running it in X86 full system simulation.(fatal: fatal condition !kernelObj occurred: No kernel to load.)

Tags: gem5

I want to run gem5 in full simulation mode in X86 processor but doesn't able to run.When try to run the command "*./build/X86/gem5.opt ./configs/example/fs.py* " getting kernel error.
[image]

I also tried to run using command " *./build/X86/gem5.opt ./configs/example/fs.py --kernel=x86_64-vmlinux-2.6.22.9.smp* " giving kernel option but it fall in runtime error.
[image]

I have seen some post over here but it doesn't help. So, please give me some idea how i can come up with solution ?

Comment: Please: 1) always provide text copy pastes instead of images 2) profile fuller error logs for the second one, the actual error message should be further below, those warnings are normal. Sample working command can be found at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/f350d28a808dbf0dd374197bfb33e6940da093c9#gem5-buildroot-setup-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

please run scons build/X86/gem5.opt
./build/X86/gem5.opt configs/example/gem5_library/x86-ubuntu-run.py

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).